# Javascript not running in order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have problem with my javascript not running in order on submit event.
i have a form more or less like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="images/loading.gif"/></div>
    <div id="hasil" style="display:none;"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and a javascript function with ajax :

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  $('#hasil').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    alert('a');
    $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if(data=='0'){
        $('#hasil').html('Code Already Exist');
        $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function() {
          alert('d');
          $('#hasil').fadeIn();
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

it supposed to show #loading, hide #loading, then show #hasil. at first submit, it will run with no problem. but when i submit it at second time, the script not running at orderly from top to bottom, instead from point 'd', then 'a' (alert()).

i wonder why the script run like this? did i made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: maybe it just so happen that your ajax returned faster than the fadeOut time of `#hasil`, try putting your ajax call inside the `#hasil` fadeOut . So that it will wait for hasil to fadeout first before calling the ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to jQuery API document: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

> the callback is fired once the animation is complete.

So, if the ajax request was completed faster than the fade out  animation, point 'd' will happen first and then point 'a'.

You can place the ajax request inside the fade out callback function to solve the problem.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    $('#hasil').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        alert('a');
        $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data=='0'){
                    $('#hasil').html('Code Already Exist');
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        alert('d');
                        $('#hasil').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i have tried it before. somehow, the server return whole page rather than do 'POST' and return data to ajax. i use firebug to log it.

Comment: This is the another issue. You need using `e.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;` in the submit event to prevent the default submit action.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i have tried that, but it still return whole page (not redirect or refresh, but in response tab inside firebug)

Comment: Sorry, `return false;` are also work in your case. Can you post your code to see the problem.

Comment: well, looks like it still not working as i wanted. it did post the data, but it seem that i can't prevent the form action. since the code working, i'll mark it. for now i'll try different approach to this.